# Removing a <div> element while hover over another element

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I've come across a problem while writing my website.

What I'm trying to do is to make the menu on the left, which is within the `.split` class disappear once the user hovers over the photos button.

Currently, it doesn't actually work (the code isn't on the actual website I'm trying this in my own text editor and it doesn't seem to work.)

Below is the code I'm trying to implement (which I read should work)

```
#button:hover .split{
  width: 0%;
}

.left {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
}
```

Furthermore, is it possible for me to implement animate.css to animate the menu out?

Below is the code for my current .split class

```
.split {
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

HTML code:

```
 <!---Main Site Slide in--->
   <div class="split left wow fadeInLeftBig animated" data-wow-duration="2s">
     <div class="centered wow ">
       <h1>####</h1>

       <p> ### </p>

    <p> #### </p>
  <div class='divider'></div>
  <div class='container'>
    <a href="" style="text-decoration:none"><h2>Previous Projects: </h2></a>

    <ul id="projects">
      <li>-Selected project 1-</li>
      <li>-Selected project 2-</li>
      <li>-Selected project 3-</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: URL is not loading for me. Connection timed out.

Comment: ( Copy and paste the link as it doesn't seem to open using the hyperlink )

Comment: Where is your HTML? You should always include your code in the question itself, and not use a link as a primary reference. What if it breaks later on?

Comment: Please provide the other CSS classes, your code should minimally run so we can help you.

Comment: @blank_ I posted an answer hope it helped?

Comment: @Salman thank you very much :) . I will check if it works as soon as I can

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When Using `:hover` the div/id after the + should be a child of the `#button` (inside of the div/id)

You could better use jQuery to add a class to the Div you want to effect.

```js
$( ".photos" ).hover(
  function() {
    $(  ".menu" ).addClass( "hover" );
  }, function() {
    $(  ".menu" ).removeClass( "hover" );
  }
);
```

```css
body{
  display:inline-flex;
}

div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s; /* Safari */
  -moz-transition: all 2s; /* Mozilla firefox */
  -ms-transition: all 2s; /* Google chrome */
  transition: all 2s;
}
.menu {
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
}
.photos {
  background-color:blue;
}
.hover {
  /*width:0px; You could do width:0; or just move the object out of view*/
  opacity:0;     
  left:-200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">menu </div>
<div class="photos">photos </div>
```